# Ignore the first two lines with ## in perl

Tags: perl

all.

Im a newbie in programming especially in perl. I would like to skip the first two lines in my dataset.

these are my codes.

```
    while (<PEPTIDELIST>) {
        next if $_ !=~ "##";
        chomp $_;
        @data = split /\t/;
        chomp $_;
        next if /Sequence/;
        chomp $_;
    $npeptides++;
 #  print "debug: 0: $data[0]  1:  $data[1]  2:  $data[2] 3:   
 $data[3]     
 \n" if ( $debug );
    my $pepseq = $data[1];
    #print $pepseq."\n";
    foreach my $header (keys %sequence) {
    #print "looking for $pepseq in $header \n";
    if ($sequence{$header} =~ /$pepseq/ ) {
       print "matched $pepseq in protein $header" if ( $debug );
        # my $in =<STDIN>;

        if ( $header =~ /(ENSGALP\S+)\s.+(ENSGALG\S+)/  ) {
            print "debug: $1  $2 have the pep = $pepseq \n\n" if (  
 $debug);
            my $lprot = $1;
            my $lgene = $2;
             $gccount{$lgene}++;
             $pccount{$lprot}++;
          #  print "$1" if($debug);
          #  print "$2" if ($debug);

                print OUT "$pepseq,$1,$2\n";
                }
            }
    }

    my $ngenes = keys %gccount;
    my $nprots = keys %pccount;
```

somehow the peptide is not in the output list. please help point me where it goes wrong?

thanks

Comment: Two things: 1. always include `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every script, and 2. you're a little [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)-happy there.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to fix the formatting of your code. Firstly, I think your comment has been split over three lines. And secondly, everyone (including you) will find your code far easier to read if you use consistent indentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip lines that contain `##` anywhere in them:

```
next if /##/;
```

If you only want to skip lines that *start* with `##`:

```
next if /^##/;
```

If you always want to skip the first two lines, regardless of content:

```
next if $. < 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

`next if $_ !=~ "##";` must be `next if $_ =~ "##";`

Ignore this lie if `$_` matched `##`